# vb.net passing eventname to method using late binding

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple methode

```
Public Sub mysub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

... here i need somehow the name of the event which has been raised

End sub
```

which I late binded as followed:

```
dyn_method = GetType(DynamicCtrlFunctions).GetMethod("mysub")
dynamicEventInfo = CTRID_Object.GetType.GetEvent("leave")

Dim eventdelegate As [Delegate]= [Delegate].CreateDelegate(dynamicEventInfo.EventHandlerType, Nothing, dyn_method)

dynamicEventInfo.AddEventHandler(myObject, eventdelegate)
```

How can I pass the name of the event within the binding process of a system.eventhandle somehow to mysub so I can fetch the event name within mysub when it has been called by the event?

Comment: I suspect this might be an "A/B Problem".  Can you tell us more about why you need to do this?

Comment: within my application the events and methodes are stored wiithin a config file. therefore i don't know at runtime which combination has been set. if the same object contains twice the same methode but using different events (i. e. enter and leave) I come in trouble fetching my specific method params which I stored in a dictionary if i don't know the event which called the methode. thx for ur help

Comment: So the problem is, given the name of a method and name of an event, how to handle said event with said method, and somehow know which event was raised in the method. Is this correct?

Comment: If I unserstand u right...the answer is yes

Comment: I just had an idea.  Testing it now, I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: thx sooooo much:-))

Comment: are these events being raised by your code? if they are, you could create your own event args class that inherits this one, add a 'EventName' property and populate it when raising the event.

Comment: I got it working, see my 2nd answer.

Comment: the problem is that the EventInfo of a standard event (i.e. 'leave' ect.) doesn't match to the eventdelegate.
'dynamicEventInfo.AddEventHandler(myObject, eventdelegate)'

Comment: @ps2goat That will work fine if he controls all the code that raises the event, but if any of the events are raised by the framework, or other code he doesn't control, it won't work.  I figured out a solution using an anonymous method, and captured variables, as a proxy event handler that can invoke the real handler with the non-standard delegate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will need some serious refactoring, but I got it to work.

it uses an anonymous method as a direct event handler for the event.  That method captures the name of the event and the real handler, and passes them off to another proxy event handler.  That proxy invokes your actual handler, passing in the name of the captured event.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim list As New List(Of HandlerInfo)
        list.Add(New HandlerInfo() With {.EventName = "Click", .HandlerName = "mysub"})
        list.Add(New HandlerInfo() With {.EventName = "MouseEnter", .HandlerName = "mysub"})
        list.Add(New HandlerInfo() With {.EventName = "MouseLeave", .HandlerName = "mysub"})

        For Each info As HandlerInfo In list
            Dim eventName As String = info.EventName 'Use local variables, rather that the iterator, or else the wrong object will get captured and it won't work correctly.
            Dim handlerName As String = info.HandlerName

            Dim dynamicEventInfo As EventInfo = Button1.GetType.GetEvent(eventName)
            dynamicEventInfo.AddEventHandler(Button1, New EventHandler(Sub(sender2 As Object, e2 As EventArgs)
                                                                           Dim t As Type = GetType(Form1) 'This is the type of the object that contains the handler
                                                                           Dim i As Object = Me 'This is the instance of "t" that the handler should be invoked on
                                                                           Dim handler As MethodInfo = t.GetMethod(handlerName)
                                                                           handler.Invoke(i, New Object() {sender2, e2, eventName})
                                                                       End Sub))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Class HandlerInfo
        Public Property EventName As String
        Public Property HandlerName As String
    End Class

    Public Sub mysub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, eventName As String)
        Debug.WriteLine(eventName)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I've refactored it a bit to inline the proxy handler.

Comment: I have no clue how u did it but..... IT WORKS GREAT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It basically creates a "Wrapper" event handler as an anonmous method that the event can call.  That handler knows what the event name is because it captures it in a closure.  It then calls your "Real" event handler, passing in the captured event name.  The anonymous method being able to form a closure around the event name is the key to making it work.  I don't think it would have been possible in older versions of the framework that don't support anonymous methods.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't think of a *good* way to do this.

That being said, you could possibly infer the event name from the `Type` of the `EventArgs` your method passed.  This definitely won't work in all cases though.

Another option would be to use reflection to examine the Call Stack.  In .NET WinForms, the common convention for events is that they are raised from a method called "On{EventName}".  So the `Click` event is raised from `OnClick`.  The previous frame of the call stack, when in an event handler, *should* have the name of that method.  You could parse that name to determine the event name.  There is no guarantee that the code author followed that convention though, or that someone didn't manually invoke your handler from someplace other than an event.

You can see an example of the call stack from inside the `Click` event of a button in the image below.
[image]

I definitely would not want to use this method in any performance critical code.

Comment: The call stack shows the method name, not the event name

Comment: Corrent, in this case "OnClick".  Like I said though, the common *convention* is that this method name is the word "on" plus the name of the event, "Click" in this case, which is the event name.  You would have to parse that method name to get the event.  I specifically said that it wasn't a *good* solution, but it is the only thing I can think of that would allow you to get the event name.

Comment: For all we know, you're right and "mysub" is really "OnLeave", but if not, then he's changing method names, and he might as well add `EventName` parameter to the event, or better yet, derive a custom EventArgs with that property.

Comment: I don't believe so.  The problem is that you don't control the code that actually invokes the event, so you have no way to supply that parameter (or add it as a property to a custom event arg).

Comment: I was also trying to add a parameter to my sub
Public Sub mysub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, PARAM as string))

with using a different delegate 
'Public Delegate Sub MyDelegate(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs, param As String)'
but then I got in trouble with 
'dynamicEventInfo.AddEventHandler(myObject, eventdelegate)'
as the signiture doesn't macht:-(

Comment: @skrskr- that's similar to my proposal on your question. if you are raising the event, just make your own class that derives from event args and add the new property.  in the event handler, you can check the type and cast it to get the name.